# Чем отличаются понятия экземпляр объекта и экземпляр класса в PHP 5?

Tags: php, ооп

Изучаю ООП PHP 5. Встретив для себя пока незнакомое англ. слово instance, решил перевести через google translate - "экземпляр объекта".
Соответственно у меня возник вопрос: какие различия у понятий "экземпляр объекта" и "экземпляр класса" в PHP 5?

И какой корректный/правильный перевод слова instance? (Вижу, в дальнейшем придётся использовать его очень часто)

Comment: Объект является экземпляром класса. Экземпляров объекта не бывает, т. к. сам объект является экземпляром

Comment: скорее всего там просто опечатка, так как все, под что выделена память является объектами, и тот же экземпляр класса, где класс это тип данных, но не объект

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instance - это и вправду "экземпляр", часто используют и вовсе транслитерацию (инстанс). Конкретно выражение "экземпляр класса" немного напрягает, но "экземпляр класса X" или просто "экземпляр X" встречаются часто, и подразумевается под этим просто объект класса X. Под "экземпляром объекта", скорее всего, имелось в виду то же самое.

Comment: Т.е. по сути разницы между понятиями "Instance" и "Object" в PHP 5 нет никакой? Получается, что это одно и тоже?